# Discord.py presence listening with an url

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Looking for a method to get the presence from a Discord bot to "listening" with an url.
As it is already the case with the streaming presence.

```
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="My Stream", url=my_twitch_url))
```

Comment: Do you want the bot to change the status depending on what he is "listening" to?

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the Activity type:

```py
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(
            type=discord.ActivityType.listening,
            name=" to my thoughts."))
```

Comment: But the URL that should be displayed when you click on it is missing.

Comment: @JarJarBinks thats mearly an example. You can add the url your self.